# To Convert CST to IST timezone

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone

My actual requirement is,

This is the input which we have in the .txt file,

The below line is having (Emp ID, Date, HH:MM:SS (that is time), Status, Site number, Reader number

123,"20/02/2019",00:00:50,IN,23,1

In the above, I have to take 123 as Emp ID and have to assign it into one variable called tv_emp_id.

```
then, have to take date and HH:MM ("20/02/2019",02:30) and convert it into IST date & time (21-02-2019,14:00)), then put date (21-02-2019 format) alone in one variable called tv_date and HHMM in another variable called tv_time (14:00 it will be 1400) by Oracle query.

Finally required it with, tv_emp_id= 123;
           tv_date = 21-02-2019
           tv_time = 1400
```

Please help me to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data - particularly the starting data type - and results.

Comment: Why 12:29 rather than 12:30? And are those dates or timestamps?

Comment: What is time zone CST and IST? Have a look with `SELECT TZABBREV, TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME), TZNAME FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES WHERE TZABBREV in ('CST', 'IST')`

Answer (score 1):

If you mean [Central Standard Time and India Standard Time](https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/cst-to-ist-converter), and you're starting from a plain timestamp:

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZD';

select timestamp '2019-03-20 02:00:00'  as original,
  from_tz(timestamp '2019-03-20 02:00:00', 'America/Chicago') as cst,
  from_tz(timestamp '2019-03-20 02:00:00', 'America/Chicago') at time zone 'Asia/Calcutta' as ist
from dual;

ORIGINAL            CST                     IST                    
------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
2019-03-20 02:00:00 2019-03-20 02:00:00 CDT 2019-03-20 12:30:00 IST
```

If you want to end up with a plain timestamp (or a date), rather than a timestamp with time zone, then case the result to the data type you want.

If you're starting from a date then you'll need to cast it to a timestamp inside the `from_tz()` call.